# How to get name data of multiple json object list that will be posted to web api?

Tags: c#, json, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a post method in Web API ASP.NET that accepts a single Json object. Here is the code with a code to check if data from the posting Json is existing in my database. and I will be using Linq to interact with my DB. Sales_ was auto-generated in my context, I believe from EntityFramework. db is my database object.

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostSales(Sales Sales, [FromUri] string auth)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {                    
                    if (auth == "KDI")
                    {

                        Int64 rs = db.Sales_.Where(sl => sl.Serial == Sales.Serial).Count();
                        if (rs == 1)
                        {
                            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, " Duplicate Found!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            db.Sales_.Add(Sales);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Added!");
                        }
//Closing elses cut out for this question.
```

That is working fine and it accepts my Json fine as a single object.

Here is my Json that will be posted.

```
{
  "Serial": 1,
  "ExtSerial": "AH0000002",
  "Date": "2015-03-01",
  "CustomerRefNbr": "JPM0001",
  "Description": "2015 FEBRUARY RENTAL  2015 FEBRUARY RENTAL",
  "Customer": "TRDE0065",
  "Amount": 17989.51,
  "AQ_Branch": "KDI",
  "AQ_COA": "4100503000",
  "LineSubAccount": "OPMOPN000",
  "LineTaxCategory": "JPMTAX",
  "LineQuantity": 1,
  "LineUnitPrice": 400000,
  "AQ_PostStatus": 1,
  "AQ_StatusDate": "2015-03-01",
  "DTS": "2015-03-01",
  "LineDescription": "Line Description"
}
```

Now, I wanted to post multiple lists or lines (not sure what to call them) in a json object. Something like this:

```
    {
      "ExtSerial": "AH0000002",
      "Date": "2015-03-01",
      "CustomerRefNbr": "JPM0001",
      "Description": "2015 FEBRUARY RENTAL  2015 FEBRUARY RENTAL",
      "Customer": "TRDE0065",
      "Amount": 17989.51,
      "AQ_Branch": "KDI",
      "AQ_COA": "4100503000",
      "LineSubAccount": "OPMOPN000",
      "LineTaxCategory": "JPMTAX",
      "LineQuantity": 1,
      "LineUnitPrice": 400000,
      "AQ_PostStatus": 1,
      "AQ_StatusDate": "2015-03-01",
      "DTS": "2015-03-01",
      "LineDescription": "Line Description"
    },{
      "ExtSerial": "AH0000003",
      "Date": "2015-04-01",
      "CustomerRefNbr": "JPM0002",
      "Description": "2015 FEBRUARY RENTAL  2015 FEBRUARY RENTAL",
      "Customer": "TRDE0066",
      " Amount": 17989.51,
      "AQ_Branch": "KDI",
      "AQ_COA": "4100503000",
      "LineSubAccount": "OPMOPN000",
      "LineTaxCategory": "JPMTAX",
      "LineQuantity": 2,
      "LineUnitPrice": 400000,
      "AQ_PostStatus": 1,
      "AQ_StatusDate": "2015-04-01",
      "DTS": "2015-04-01",
      "LineDescription": "Line Description"
}
```

Not sure how it will be read on my post method though. I have tried changing my parameter Sales to `List<Sales> Sales`. I think that is what to use for a list in an object but my problem is that my `db.Sales_.Add(Sales);` is producing an error now. (invalid arguments) Not sure how to use the .Add() with a list. Also, I can't get the data of my Sales table column serial as shown in                         `Int64 rs = db.Sales_.Where(sl => sl.Serial == Sales.Serial).Count();`

I'm pretty much stuck and don't know how to do this. I hope you don't find my question stupid. I just need your help. I know it's a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

JSON arrays are wrapped in [], also your Sales argument must be of list or array.

Change your method signature to

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostSales(List<Sales> Sales, [FromUri] string auth)
```

Change your json to be wrapped in [] like

```
[{
      "ExtSerial": "AH0000002",
      "Date": "2015-03-01",
      "CustomerRefNbr": "JPM0001",
      "Description": "2015 FEBRUARY RENTAL  2015 FEBRUARY RENTAL",
      "Customer": "TRDE0065",
      "Amount": 17989.51,
      "AQ_Branch": "KDI",
      "AQ_COA": "4100503000",
      "LineSubAccount": "OPMOPN000",
      "LineTaxCategory": "JPMTAX",
      "LineQuantity": 1,
      "LineUnitPrice": 400000,
      "AQ_PostStatus": 1,
      "AQ_StatusDate": "2015-03-01",
      "DTS": "2015-03-01",
      "LineDescription": "Line Description"
    },{
      "ExtSerial": "AH0000003",
      "Date": "2015-04-01",
      "CustomerRefNbr": "JPM0002",
      "Description": "2015 FEBRUARY RENTAL  2015 FEBRUARY RENTAL",
      "Customer": "TRDE0066",
      " Amount": 17989.51,
      "AQ_Branch": "KDI",
      "AQ_COA": "4100503000",
      "LineSubAccount": "OPMOPN000",
      "LineTaxCategory": "JPMTAX",
      "LineQuantity": 2,
      "LineUnitPrice": 400000,
      "AQ_PostStatus": 1,
      "AQ_StatusDate": "2015-04-01",
      "DTS": "2015-04-01",
      "LineDescription": "Line Description"
}]
```

Now you just enumerate through your `Sales` and process each one individually.  Something like

```
Parallel.ForEach(Sales, sale => {
//you can clean this up using Any(), instead of Where.. 
//Int64 rs = db.Sales_.Where(sl => sl.Serial == sale.Serial).Count();
    using (var dbContext = new YourDatabaseContext())
    {
                        if (dbContext .Sales_.Any(sl => sl.Serial == sale.Serial))
                        {
                            return;  //ignore duplicates
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dbContext .Sales_.Add(sale);
                            dbContext .SaveChanges();
                        }
    }
});
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Finished");
//you can just return OK considering a duplicate will not break the client.
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an exception on the if statement: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: I updated my code to create the db context in the `Parallel.ForEach`  If your json array is only a few objects, you are going to be better off not createing the db context in the `Parallel.ForEach` and just using a regular synchronous foreach.  If your json array can be 100's, you should look at adding a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` option to the `Parallel.ForEach`.