# How to fix this exception type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

This is continuation to my question: [[How to get name data of multiple json object list that will be posted to web api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177075/how-to-get-name-data-of-multiple-json-object-list-that-will-be-posted-to-web-api][1])

I was able to update my code but now I am getting an erexception on

```
if (db.Sales1.Any(sl => sl.ExtSerial != s.ExtSerial))
```

Exception goes: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Here is the code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostSales(List<Sales> Sales, [FromUri] string auth)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (auth == "KDI")
                    {
                        #region Stable but not multiline
                        //Int64 rs = db.Sales1.Where(sl => sl.Serial == Sales.Serial).Count();
                        //if (1 == rs)
                        //{
                        //    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, " Duplicate Found!");
                        //}
                        //else
                        //{
                        //    db.Sales1.Add(Sales);
                        //    db.SaveChanges();
                        //    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Added!");
                        //} 
                        #endregion
                        Parallel.ForEach(Sales, s =>
                        {
                            if (db.Sales1.Any(sl => sl.ExtSerial != s.ExtSerial))
                            {
                                db.Sales1.Add(s);
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                        });
                        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized Access!");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Something's wrong with the JSON model you sent me.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't think that making concurrent changes and saves on a db will work like that. Do you get the same exception if you remove the 'parallel' part?

Comment: When I removed Parallel, I could not enumerate sales (unless you have some suggestions I can use?). If I can't enumerate, I can't post multiple-lined json object, I assume.

Comment: maybe, foreach (var sale in Sales)